# Get Outlook Express contacts from old HDD?

Tags: windows-7, windows, outlook-express

I just installed Windows 7 on some new hardware. I forgot to export the contacts from Outlook Express. I've put in the old hdd in the new pc. Is it possible to get the contacts from there, or do I have to put in the old hardware and boot from the old hdd?

Comment: Personally I would just boot from the old hard drive and get it that way.  Finding those files, and importing them *can* be a pain at times.

Comment: Is it Outlook or Outlook Express contacts you are interested in? Where the contacts reside depends on which one you mean.

Comment: It's Outlook Express...

Comment: I'll probably try booting on the new hardware. If it doesn't work I'll just have to install the old hardware again... :(

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Express

Search the hard drive for .wab file(s)